# directory path by handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filepath

How to get full directory path by `HANDLE`?

[GetFileInformationByHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953(v=vs.85).aspx) returns path without disk letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is probably your best bet.